# Postgres ANY operator with array selected in a subquery

Tags: postgresql

Can someone explain to me why the 4th select works, but the first 3 do not? (I'm on PostgreSQL 9.3.4 if it matters.)

```
drop table if exists temp_a;
create temp table temp_a as
(
    select array[10,20] as arr
);

select 10 = any(select arr from temp_a);    -- ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

select 10 = any(select arr::integer[] from temp_a); -- ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

select 10 = any((select arr from temp_a));  -- ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]

select 10 = any((select arr from temp_a)::integer[]);   -- works
```

Here's a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56a09/2

Comment: The same results occur for 9.2.9.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be expecting an aggregate. Per the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

> Note: Boolean aggregates `bool_and` and `bool_or` correspond to standard SQL aggregates `every` and `any` or `some`. As for any and some, it seems that there is an ambiguity built into the standard syntax:
>
> ```
> SELECT b1 = ANY((SELECT b2 FROM t2 ...)) FROM t1 ...;
> ```
>
> Here ANY can be considered either as introducing a subquery, or as being an aggregate function, if the subquery returns one row with a Boolean value. Thus the standard name cannot be given to these aggregates.

In Postgres, the `any` operator exists [for subqueries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) and [for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html).

The first three queries return a set of values of type `int[]` and you're comparing them to an `int`. Can't work.

The last query is returning an `int[]` array but it's only working because you're returning a single element.

Exhibit A; this works:

```
select (select i from (values (array[1])) rows(i))::int[];
```

But this doesn't:

```
select (select i from (values (array[1]), (array[2])) rows(i))::int[];
```

This works as a result (equivalent to your fourth query):

```
select 1 = any((select i from (values (array[1])) rows(i))::int[]);
```

But this doesn't (equivalent to your fourth query returning multiple rows):

```
select 1 = any((select i from (values (array[1]), (array[2])) rows(i))::int[]);
```

These should also work, btw:

```
select 1 = any(
             select unnest(arr) from temp_a
           );
select 1 = any(
             select unnest(i)
             from (values (array[1]), (array[2])) rows(i)
           );
```

Also note the `array(select ...))` construct as an aside, since it's occasionally handy:

```
select 1 = any(array(
             select i
             from (values (1), (2)) rows(i)
           ));
select 1 = any(
             select i
             from (values (1), (2)) rows(i)
           );
```

Comment: Fascinating and obscure. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: When I read this, I thought `rows()` was a keyword, but it's just the way of naming an anonymous table/row. In this case, it's naming the values as a one-off table named `rows`. This syntax works too: `select 1 = any(select mycol from (values (1), (2))  AS mytable (mycol))`.